# Am I doing this counting problem correctly?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

$12$ people were asked which of the three television channel ch1, ch2, and ch3 they watch. How many possible results there could be? (For example, one result would be 8 people watch ch1, 10 people watch ch2, and no one watches ch3.

My answer is $12\times2^3$. Is this correct?

For each person, they could watch ch1 or not, then watch ch2 or not, and watch ch3 or not so for each person there are $2^3$ possibilities.

Comment: It depends on what you precisely mean by a "result". You hint that in the end, only the number of how many people watch a certain channel, is counted. It doesn't matter who watches which channel. And these numbers are completely independent. In that case, you can just look at the different channels. There are three channels, and each can be watched by zero to 12 people. So that would give $13^3$ ...

Comment: Take back the previous comment. It seems you are counting only *how many people are watching each channel*, not *which channel each person is watching exactly*. Please specify what exactly you are counting out of these two.

Answer (score 1):

$12$ people are watching the television. A television can have $3$ states.

There are $3^{12} = 531441$ possibilities.

If you have zero or more non-viewers amongst these people the correct answer would be: $4^{12} = 16777216$ possibilities.

Description:

There is $c^p$ number of possibilities where $c$ equal the total number of channels and $p$ equal the total number of people watching.

Why?

```
no.  person 1   person 2  etc....
1       0          0
2       0          1
3       0          2
4       1          0
5       1          1
6       1          2
7       2          0
8       2          1
9       2          2
.       .          .
.       .          .
```

The truth table show that if there where only $2$ persons and only $3$ channels there would be $3^2 = 9$ possibilities. For larger number of people one could extend this truth table. Its increasing exponentially.

Answer (score -1):

I think the answer should be :-

(1)If each person can choose only one channel :- (3)^12, as each person has three options, and each one could choose any one of the three.

(2) If a person has to choose atleast one channel :- (3C1 + 3C2 + 3C3)^12 = 7^12

(3) If a person can choose any number of channels (from 0 to 3) :- (3C0 + 3C1 + 3C2 + 3C3)^12 = 8^12

Comment: $3^{12}$ can be a correct answer ONLY if the requirement is that everyone specify exactly one channel as their answer. If they can answer any number (including none) it would be different (much bigger).

Comment: Oh yes I apologise, I assumed the simplification. I'll try to edit it. Thanks for pointing out 

Comment: I think it's correct now? @PVanchinathan

Comment: As each can choose any subset the answer us $8^{12} $ counting empty subset as a possibility.  Your revised answer is correct for the case where all the answers are nonempty

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot! I'll re-edit. Basically I was as lost(if not more) than the OP.   Also, the answer by Robert Z seems to be different (and hence wrong), since people can like multiple channels so x1 + x2 +x3 is not necessarily equal to 12.(Eg. It may even be 36 in the case that all people like all the channeps) Right?